# ConEmu:Send SIGINT to running application

Tags: conemu

as Ctrl+C copies the current selection rather than killing the current application in ConEmu, I wonder how to do the latter now. I know that there is Ctrl+Alt+Break (Terminate (kill) active process in the current console: Close(1)), but does this behave the same as pressing Ctrl+C in a plain old cmd.exe window?
AFAIK Ctrl+C usually sends SIGINT (or whatever windows has instead) prior to killing the window so that the application can exit voluntarily.

Thanks!

Comment: Look at GuiMacro `Break`.

Comment: Thank you for your hint!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to assign the hotkey Ctrl+C to an arbitrary macro (01-32) that is configured to run "Break(1)":
[image: screenshot]

The existing binding of Ctrl+C to the "Copy" command must be removed.