# ConEmu CTRL+C not passed to grep in wslbridge.exe

Tags: conemu

I am using ConEmu with the `wslbridge.exe`. I am incapable to pass down CTRL+C to cancel a `grep` that takes too long. Or an `ls` or any long command that displays stdout. I've followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41092044/3424564) answer but still no result. Anyone faced this that can help me? For the record `^C` is correctly passed in any other scenarios. This just happens with commands that display stdout output.

Thanks.

Comment: It passed actually. But at the moment when you press Ctrl+C the grep is already finishes its work, and what you see is a transfer of existing output from WSL to ConEmu. I hope the speed would be enhanced in future releases.

Comment: Thanks Maximus. Appreciated.